# Umbraco httppost error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: umbraco

I want to send a model to the action of the HomePost controller, I shot UmbracoForm and surface controller, when I run it and I click submit I get the error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object".

ViewModel:

```
 namespace Umbraco12.Models
    {
        public class Home : RenderModel
        {
            public Home(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture)
            {
            }

            public string Topic { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeSurController : SurfaceController
    {
        // GET: HomeSur
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult HomePost(Home model)
        {

            //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
            return View("Home", model);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco12.Models.Home>
    @using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
    @{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
    }
   @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("HomePost", "HomeSur", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "YourclassName" }))
    {
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Umbraco.Field("topic")</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Topic)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
```